# Proof of Rayleigh's stability criterion for a rotating inviscid fluid using linear perturbation equations

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, centrifugal-force, stability

This question is concerned with **how to prove Rayleigh's stability criterion
for a rotating inviscid fluid**. I can follow the details of the proof up to the
final line, but I cannot see immediately how the conclusion is deduced.

This stability criterion considers a purely
azimuthal flow ${\bf u} = V(r) \,{\bf e}_\theta = r\,\Omega\, {\bf e}_\theta$, where $\Omega$
is the angular velocity of the flow and ${\bf e}_r,\; {\bf e}_\theta$ are unit vectors in
a cylindrical coordinate system. The criterion states that a necessary and sufficient for condition for the stability of this flow to axisymmetric disturbances is that
$$\frac{d}{dr} \left( \Omega r^2 \right)^2 \geq 0 $$ throughout the flow. (See for example
`Elementary Fluid Dynamics', D. J. Acheson, pg 318).
This result can be demonstrated through energy arguments that involve displacing small elements of fluid and arguing for conservation of angular momentum. However, I am instead
interested in a rigorous proof of this result based directly on the perturbation equations of linear stability.
To do this we introduce infinitesimal perturbations of the form ${u}_r = \hat{u}_r \, e^{st + inz}$ (with similar expressions for the other variables), where $s$ is in general complex and $n$ real. Note that the stability of the flow is determined by the sign of the real part of $s$. When $\Re(s) > 0$ the disturbance will grow (i.e. the flow is unstable) while the disturbance will decay (the flow is stable) when  $\Re(s) < 0$.  We eventually end up with the equation
(see Acheson pg 382)
$$ s^2 \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \left\{ r \mid \hat{u}_r' \mid^2 + r\left(n^2 + \frac{1}{r^2}\right) \mid \hat{u}_r \mid^2 \right\} \, dr = - \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \frac{n^2}{r^2}(r^2 V^2)' \mid \hat{u}_r \mid^2  \, dr $$
Since the integral on the lhs is positive, we can thus deduce :
\begin{eqnarray*}
(r^2 V^2)'  &= \frac{d}{dr} \left( \Omega r^2 \right)^2  > 0 \text{ everywhere } \Rightarrow s^2 < 0,\\
(r^2 V^2)'  &= \frac{d}{dr} \left( \Omega r^2 \right)^2  < 0 \text{ everywhere } \Rightarrow s^2 > 0. \\
(r^2 V^2)'  & \text {changes sign } \Rightarrow s^2 \text{ can have either sign }
\end{eqnarray*}

So far so good! The question is how do we for example then deduce  stability (to axisymmetric disturbances) when $\frac{d}{dr} \left( \Omega r^2 \right)^2  > 0 $?
In this case we have that $s^2 < 0$ which means that $s$ must be purely imaginary.
This means that the real part of $s$ is zero which is surely 'neutral stability' (a
disturbance which neither grows nor decays), rather than stability ?
Furthermore when $\frac{d}{dr} \left( \Omega r^2 \right)^2  < 0 $ we have that $s^2 > 0$
which means that $s$ must be real. However here $s$ can be either positive (instability)
*or* negative (stability) -  since we haven't proven it is positive, how can we claim the flow is unstable?

Comment: What is $R$ in $s^R$? If it is intended to mean the real part, usually one uses $\Re(s)$ (`$\Re(s)$`) to denote that. Your notation makes it confusing when you later write $s^2$ (which one might take to mean that $R=2$).

Comment: Hi Kyle, Thanks for your comment - I have edited the post to avoid any possible confusion.

Comment: if not too long, maybe, you could indicate how the result was derived; just looking at it one may assume that the $s^2$ on the left of the integral may just be a typo in which case ...

Comment: Hi Hyportnex,It doesn't seem to be a typo -  the same result is in 'Hydrodynamic Stability' Drazin & Reid, pg 78. They conclude `the eigenvalues $n^2/s^2$ are all negative if $\Phi = \frac{1}{r^3} \frac{d}{dr} \left(\Omega r^2 \right)^2  > 0$ throughout the interval $r_1 < r < r_2$, and they are all positive if $\Phi < 0$. However if $\Phi$ changes sign we have both positive and negative eigenvalues'.  It appears this result was first found by J. L. Synge, 'the stability of heterogeneous liquids' Trans. R. Soc. Canada **27**, 1-18 (1933). It is not in my university's library unfortunately!

Comment: Interesting. Synge is freely available here:  https://community.ams.org/publicoutreach/math-history/procsemi-synge.pdf

Comment: Hi Hyportnex, Many thanks for the link. The paper you have linked is not the original reference (that is an 18 page article, the paper above is a 43 page article), and appears to be a review article from what I can see from a  quick first glance. It might be that it includes the same analysis, I will need to have a longer look and get back to you. Thanks again for sending it though - it looks like an interesting article either way!

Comment: this may help, see page 3-4: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.02815.pdf